# SQLite.Net-PCL in Metro App using VB.NET - missing classes

Tags: vb.net, sqlite, microsoft-metro

I have included `SQLite.Net-PCL v2.3.0` in my Metro app but it seems some classes are missing.

```
Dim MyPlatform = new SQLite.Net.Platform.WinRT.SQLitePlatformWinRT()
  Using connection = New SQLiteConnection(MyPlatform , _dbPath)
End Using
```

`**SQLite.Net.Platform.WinRT.SQLitePlatformWinRT**` class is not recognized.
Tried adding `SQLite.Net.Platform.WinRT`first  but no success. IT says:
 "To use this package you will need to install one of the platform packages or write your own implementation of ISQLitePlatform." (taken from https://www.nuget.org/packages/SQLite.Net.Platform.WinRT/)
What does it mean to implement my own interface ? I know my platform is WinRT, why can't I just use that version?

Any sample code or solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to download and copy the sqlite3.dll in all the projects. See the following documentation:

https://sqlitepcl.codeplex.com/documentation

It will explain for each type of project

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow Luis. Please explain your answer here and then add documentation as references. Otherwise your answer will become invalid if link you provided will change or be removed.